# How to simplify the use of addClass using Jquery when i have both text and a variable

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to improve this code to not use addClass multiple times?

```
$('#element').addClass('classname classname').addClass(variablecontainingclass);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By using string concatenation:

```
 $('#element').addClass('classname classname '+variablecontainingclass)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not `$('#element').addClass('classname classname '+variablecontainingclass);` ?